# Move UIView Programmatically in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm having a UIView which is containing some labels in the prototype cell.  I want to move the view slightly upward that is change the "Y" position of the view. How can I do it ? Any help will be grateful.

I've already tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
if (self.data[indexPath.row].valueForKey("TableType") as! Int) != 3{

 cell.MoverView.frame = CGRectMake(6.0, 65.0, self.view.frame.width, 178)}
```

Comment: Your code is kind of strange. First, instances should start with a lowercase letter. Second, every `!` is a potential crash. Third, `valueForKey` is kind of old. Im my opinion there are better ways to get values. Fourth, string literals should only be used to define constants.

Comment: I'm new to iOS app development but thanks for informing this.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet in your view controller to store a reference to your "Center Y Alignment constraint". Make sure you connect it in your storyboard.

You can set the constraint's constant property to offset it from the Y position (positive number will move it down, negative moves it up).

```
@IBOutlet var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
  yConstraint.constant = -200
```

This would move your view 200 points up.

That's it. Now you can change it with the help of constraints.